# Problems with GNU Make dynamic rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, rust

I'm trying to setup a Makefile to compile my Rust project. To speed things up I don't want to recompile the whole project all at once. Rust allows you to create libraries that can then be linked into the main executable. Given two files `src/iomrascalai.rs` (the main program) and `src/board/mod.rs` (the library) to compile it by hand it would work like this:

```
$ rustc --out-dir lib src/board/mod.rs
$ ls lib/
libboard-d085aa56-0.0.rlib
$ rustc --out-dir bin -L lib src/iomrascalai.rs
$ ls bin/
iomrascalai
```

What I'm trying to do in the Makefile is to define dynamic rules to compile the libraries. I'm trying to do it like that as the mapping from source file (`src/board/mod.rs`) to library name (`lib/libboard-d085aa56-0.0.rlib`) is non-trivial. However, I can't seem to make it work:

```
MAIN   = src/iomrascalai.rs
CRATES = src/board/mod.rs

LIBS   = $(foreach crate, $(CRATES), $(call TO_LIB, $(crate)))

all: exe

exe: $(MAIN) $(LIBS)
    rustc --out-dir bin -L lib $(MAIN)

TO_LIB = $(addprefix lib/, $(shell rustc --crate-file-name $(1)))

define COMPILE_CRATE
$(call TO_LIB, $(1)): $(1)
    rustc --out-dir lib $(1)
endef

$(foreach crate, $(CRATES), $(eval $(call COMPILE_CRATE, $(crate))))
```

Running `make` results in the following error:

```
$ make
rustc --out-dir bin -L lib src/iomrascalai.rs
src/iomrascalai.rs:22:1: 22:20 error: can't find crate for `board`
src/iomrascalai.rs:22 extern crate board;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
make: *** [exe] Error 101
```

So the libraries aren't compiled which means that the main program can't be compiled. When I try to run make to compile the lib target then it works:

```
$ rustc --crate-file-name src/board/mod.rs
libboard-d085aa56-0.0.rlib
$ make lib/libboard-d085aa56-0.0.rlib
rustc --out-dir lib  src/board/mod.rs
```

So for some reason the `exe` doesn't honor the prerequisites even though the rules are defined ...

Comment: If I add `libs: $(LIBS)` and call `make libs` I get `make: libs is up to date.`. So for some reason even though the libraries aren't compiled make things that there's nothing to do.

Comment: Library crate roots should by convention be named `lib.rs`. `mod.rs` is for non-root modules.

Comment: Thanks Chris. My idea here is to simulate the C approach of compiling each file into an object file and then just recompiling the individual files as needed. That's why I used `mod.rs` as I'm not really building stand alone libraries. I wonder however if this the right approach to speed up the compilation process.

Comment: Such a model is certainly not idiomatic in Rust. Also, while at present it will improve performance in some situations, it will probably not have a net positive effect on performance and will, in the long run, certainly be counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm very interested in that subject and I'd like to get it right. I've now asked the question on the mailing list to hopefully get a few people to chime in: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-May/009765.html

Comment: I wish to clarify my earlier statement a little. I do not mean to say that a completely monolithic approach is the right way, that an entire codebase should be one crate; often it makes sense to split it up into a few, especially if there are completely distinct portions or if some parts can be used separately in other places (where you may end up with a DAG rather than a tree as your crate dependency structure). But don’t go overboard with dozens of tiny crates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively expanded make variables (those which are assigned with `=`) are expanded whenever the variable is substituted. That means, other variables you use need to be defined before. In your case, you need to move up the definition of `TO_LIB` a few lines (at least above the exe rule since the expansion of `LIBS` need to have `TO_LIB` available there)

Comment: Duh. I should have realised that reordering stuff could work. Thanks!